# How to build a multi-module Maven JavaFX Project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-13

I am trying to build a multi module Maven application, each of those modules I want to be JavaFx modules.

However I always get the following error when I try to run the application:

> "Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project parent: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java are missing or invalid"

Parent `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>hellofx</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>the-parent</name>
</project>
```

Module of parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>



<artifactId>hellofx</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>hellofx</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <mainClass>org.openjfx.MainApp</mainClass>
</properties>

<organization>
    <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
    <name>Your Organisation</name>
</organization>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.openjfx.MainApp</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Project Structure:

- TheProject

  - `.idea`
  - `hellofx`

    - `.idea`
    - `src`
    - `pom.xml`
  - `src`
  - `pom.xml`

Comment: I realize this is an old question... But maybe a solution is to use the [JavaFX Maven plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin). My problem is to get that plugin to work with a multi-module project...

Answer (score -2):

Points on the root of your project with your CMD window and use this command :

`mvn clean install -T 1.5C`

FYI : [Check the Parallel builds in Maven](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3)

Comment: This is most unclear. What have parallel builds to do with this problem?